# android data bindings using generics java

Tags: java, android, generics, android-databinding

i am newbiew in an android databinding,i wanna use generics type in an databinding layout ,
is it possible or not please tell me?

JAVA activity

```
public class SearchableActivity<R> extends ErpActivity<R extends MasterPojo>
{

  public  void callToBack(R r){
  } 
}
```

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="task"
        type="R extends Masterpojo" />

    <variable
        name="activity"
        type="com.cloud9.erp.activities.SearchableActivity<R>" />


</data>

<TextView
    style="@style/valued_style"
    android:onClick="@{() -> activity.callToBack(task)}"
    android:text="Erp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fab_margin" />
</layout>
```

Comment: why are you putting generics in your Activity?

Comment: because its use for multiple list using different model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it`s possible doing a scape for your generic type:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="activity"
        type="com.cloud9.erp.activities.SearchableActivity&lt;R>" />
</data>
```

Keep in mind that  the `Android Studio` will still show a "Cannot resolve symbol" error, but your layout file will compile.

Also, this is not the best implementation to do that, you should use Handlers for this kind of operations:

```
public class MyHandlers {
    public void onClickFriend(View view) { ... }
}
```

And then, use it in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="handlers" type="com.example.Handlers"/>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"
           android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanx bro , can you tell me how i used in xml when generic typr just like this

Comment: i have one quiestion also , please check i edited quiestion